# How to build with --prod flag in VSTS build definition in azure

Tags: azure-devops, angular6, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to write a **build definition** for my angular 6 application in azure. I want to build my angular application with **ng build --prod** flag.

My build definition looks like this:

[image]

Also my previous build step looks like this:

[image]

And I have tried this:
[build with --prod flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDwOA.png)

Am I missing anything here? Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case, somebody needs it. This is how I fixed my problem.

In npm custom build definition:

**Command and arguments** :  **run ng run "Website:build:production"**

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `--prod` flag in the "Command and arguments" field (where now you have `run ng build`).

Comment: @ShaykiAmbramczyk Sir, I've tried but not working. It's still taking the ng build as an argument.

Comment: try to remove the `run`. try also `ng build --env=prod`.